# Finding out range of values of $a$ for which $f(x)$ is decreasing

Tags: maxima-minima, monotone-functions

The question is to find out the values of $a$ for which the function $f(x)=(a+2)x^3-3ax^2+9ax-1$ decreases for all real values of $x.$

What i have tried:

I know that for a function to be decreasing, $f'(x) < 0$, So,$$f'(x)=3(a+2)x^2-6ax+9a <0$$But what to do after this because its an inequality with two variables ?

Comment: Hint: How does the discriminant of a quadratic help you?  Why is $a<-2$?

Comment: `I know that for a function to be decreasing, f′(x)<0` That's a sufficient condition, but it's not necessary. Consider for example $f(x)=-x^3$ which is *strictly* decreasing on $\mathbb{R}$, but $f'(0)=0\,$.

Answer (score 3):

First, the derivative *must* be a downwards parabola, so $\;a+2<0\;$ , and second: it must have at most one single root, so

$$\Delta:=(6a)^2-108a(a+2)\le0$$

Solve now the above two inequalities

Answer (score 0):

You want $f'(x) < 0$ for *all* $x$. In order for this to happen, you need

- $f'(x) \to -\infty $ as $x \to \pm \infty$. This happens when $a+2 < 0$
- The critical point of $f'(x)$ has to be non-positive and a maximum (so the entirety of $f'(x)$ is smaller than some negative value).

In order to work out the second condition, you can take the derivative of $f'(x)$, which is $f''(x) = 6(a+2)x-6a$. You can see that $f''(x) = 0$ when $x = \dfrac{a}{a+2}$

- The maximum occurs when the second derivative of $f'(x)$ is negative, or $f'''(x) = 6(a+2) < 0$. This brings us back to the first bullet point.
- You also need $f'\left(\dfrac{a}{a+2}\right) = \dfrac{-3a^2}{a+2} + 9a \le 0$. You're free to solve this single-variable equality on your own. The answer is $x \le -3$ or $x \ge 0$.

---

An easier way is to observe that $f'(x)$ is a parabola. For $f'(x)$ to be nonpositive, we want the parabola to lie entire below or just touching the $x$-axis. This happens hen it has a double root or no real roots, or when the determinant is nonpositive 
$$ \Delta = (6a)^2 - 4\cdot3(a+2)\cdot 9a \le 0 $$

Comment: Shouldn’t the first condition be on $f(x)$ rather than its derivative?

Comment: @amd We're looking for conditions where $f'(x)$ is always negative. An equivalent condition would be $f(+\infty)=-\infty$ and $f(-\infty)=+\infty$

Comment: $f'(x)\to-\infty$ is unnecessary. You can have $f'(x)\lt0$ without that. Indeed, $f:x\mapsto e^{-x}$ has $f'(x)\lt0$ everywhere, but $lim_{x->\infty}f(x)=0$. For that matter, neither it nor its derivatives have any critical points, so the second criterion isn’t generally applicable, either.

Comment: I guess this doesn't apply to all functions, but it came from the observation that for this particular case, $f(\infty) \to \pm \infty$ and the sign of the infinity depends on the paremeter. This condition is necessary to obtain the solution. It's still important to check how the limit behaves. If the limit is finite, we then need to make sure that $f'(\infty) \le 0$

Comment: For the second condition, I mean that **if** $f'(x)$ has critical points, then so and so must be true. If it doesn't, then life is easier.

Comment: `You want f′(x)<0 for all x` The weaker condition is sufficient that $f'(x) \color{red}{\le} 0$ with only isolated $0$s, consider $f(x)=-x^3$ for example (and even that condition can be weakened further). In the case here, $a=-3$ is included in the solution set, since it gives $f(x)= -(x-3)^3-28\,$ which is *strictly* decreasing.

Comment: I considered $-x^3$ to be non-increasing, but I think I'm wrong. Thanks for pointing out isolated zeroes